# Hide Apple menu on second monitor

Tags: macos, finder, display

How to hide the menu bar that shows up on the second monitor? I tried searching in the following settings:

- Finder preferences <kbd>⌘,</kbd>
- System settings :: Desktop & Screensaver
- System settings :: Displays

I thought it would be on SS :: Displays :: Arrangement, where we position the menu in one screen or another dragging the white box, but nope. I'm running OS X 10.9.4.

[image: settings displays arrangement]

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in this blog post [Hide The Menu Bar On Your Secondary Monitor With Mavericks](http://www.cultofmac.com/255910/hide-the-menu-bar-on-your-secondary-monitor-with-mavericks-os-x-tips/). Uncheck the option "separate Spaces" on Mission Control:

[image: mission control separate spaces]

Comment: Unchecking Displays have separate Spaces will restore the classic Spaces behaviour of the extended virtual desktop. Personally, that's behaviour that I prefer. Managing 6 extended desktops is a lot better than 12 separate ones. It keeps my workflow organized. :)

Comment: +1 I switched off Separate Spaces on day one. I much prefer my screens to shift in pairs.